# Пунктуация (несколько предложений)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Как-то после подобного сообщения, желания говорить больше не было.
>   Ну, вот именно так и будет. А теперь – подъем. И связать свою жизнь с
>   этим человеком... нет. Точнее – с человеком из этой семьи - я просто
>   не могу. Я ошибся, позвонив вместо матери — бабушке. Был бы я не
>   плотником – обязательно бы поступил иначе.

Уместны ли данные знаки препинания? Поясните свой ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какие именно? В тексте их много.

Comment: Все, кроме запятой после "я ошибся" и многоточия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу неуместность первой запятой, для неё просто нет оснований - это не оборот, обычное сочетание - обстоятельство времени.

Запятая после НУ зависит от смысла: если это эмоции - нужна, потому что это междометие, если просто усилительная частица и паузы между НУ и ВОТ нет - не нужна.

Следующий фрагмент с парцелляцией лучше соединить в одно предложение, а то смысл затемнён: к чему относится это НЕТ - к *связать жизнь* или к *точнее*.

Как варианты: И связать свою жизнь с этим человеком... -  нет, точнее, с человеком из этой семьи - я просто не могу.

И связать свою жизнь с этим человеком, точнее, с человеком из этой семьи... - нет, я просто не могу.

Тире после *точнее* и *матери* интонационное, это на усмотрение автора, только лишние тире тоже не украшают. Многоточие тоже от смысла, который вкладывает автор: где пауза раздумья, там и ставит.

Comment: А возможно сохранение парцелляции? Дело в том, что в оригинальном тексте присутствует еще одно предложение:
И связать свою жизнь с этим человеком... нет. С человеком, причинившим мне столько боли... нет! Точнее, с человеком из этой семьи - я просто не могу.

Comment: В таком случае - да, это уже фигура речи.